# Connecting a Java Application through ODBC to an Unknown SQL Data Source

Tags: java, jdbc, odbc, jdbc-odbc

I have written a Java application where it should connect to "any" SQL based data source/database through Microsoft's ODBC connection and run SQL queries.  I used the native Sun/Oracle JDBC-ODBC bridge to serve this very purpose.  However, I don't seem to be getting the right data type for certain/random fields, depending on which database I get connected to.  For instance, I get a "1.0" for a field where I should be getting a plane integer "1" and for date fields I get different timestamps which could be entirely different to what is originally set on the data source's tables.

I also know that the JDBC-ODBC driver provided by Sun/Oracle is an experimental driver and I'm guessing that is the cause of my issue, so I should be looking for a different driver.

Please keep in mind that as part of the requirements, everything should go through ODBC connections.

Is there any comprehensive drivers out there that could treat the majority of databases and come up with the right ResultSets in terms of their original types?

If not, how do you think I should get around this situation where I have no clue what database my application is dealing with at each particular instance?

Many Thanks,

Comment: Try any ORM Framework in Java like Hibernate

Comment: Could you please elaborate on that a bit?  I'm reading through the documents as we speak, so Hibernate would stand in the middle of JDBC-ODBC driver and the data source and ensures that right ResultSet is returned?  Sorry if I sound a bit confused but your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Refer this link    https://community.jboss.org/wiki/Managingmultipledatabasestransparently?_sscc=t